# byte vs char vs int Types

Tags: c#, c

I have a little basic issue.
In C there is no `byte` type so I defined it as `unsigned char` to hold buffer to system file I need to read and handle.
My C program now needs to work with C# which has `byte` built-in type but defined as 'unsigned int'.

Would it cause any issues in casting back and forth between the two systems ? 
I think no matter what "word" it is used the underlying storage remains unchanged, right. So doing something like

```
//C#
//byte[] b=new byte[2];
//b[0]=11;
//b[1]=12;
C
byte b[2];//unsigned char
b[0]=(byte)(11);
b[1]=(byte)(12);
```

is indifferent among the two.

Comment: `C` or `C++`? Are you trying to convert your program to C# or just have two programs talk to each other?

Comment: Note: those casts are useless.

Comment: What's the problem ? Your `byte` type is an 8 bit unsigned integer value and the `byte` type in C# is also an 8 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard has defined `int8_t` since C99. Use that for an 8 bit type, or `uint8_t` for the unsigned analogue.

Take care when using such a type in a structure though, there's no guarantee that adjacent members will be contiguous in memory. You'll be fine with arrays though.

Comment: oh cool I have to use quite a lot of uintxx_t in my program but overlooked the number 8. :D I'm more confident to continue swimming now.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the valuetype in C is a 'int'-number, there should be no problem casting this back and forth.